# How to convert String to Boolean Logic?

Tags: python, string, if-statement, exec

I have sting input like:

```
12 == 21
(10 != 12) or (15 == 13)
True and (10 == 10)
```

And i need to return boolean value of this input. Can i convert it using `exec()` or `bool()`? I don't want to write big method to solve it .

Comment: `eval` will work... as long as you trust the strings not to contain malicious code

Comment: there are a lot of evaluation packages. Like simpleeval for instance.

Comment: It works. Thank you